# I cant seem to thread properly

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading

Running some code that parses through a list from internal memory, the list being created from parsing an outside file.  Now I'm trying to thread going through the list and connecting to varius routers and switches, however the threading doesn't seem to be improving speed. The is_alive method returns False.

I've tried iterating over the list outside of the threaded() function and inside of it with no results. With or without threading it comes to 7.5 seconds flat each time in test environment.

Any suggestions on where I may be going wrong?

```
def connection_handler(address_list = [], configuration_block=[], dev_type="autodetect"):
print(time.time())
if 1:
    def threaded():

        for i in address_list:
            var = i.split(",")
            ip_address, username, password, secret = str(var[0]).strip(), \
                str(var[1]).strip(), str(var[2]).strip(), str(var[3]).strip()
            connection = ConnectHandler(host=str(ip_address), username=username, password=password,
                                                                 secret=secret, device_type=dev_type)
            connection.enable()
            result = connection.send_command("show run")
            result = result.replace("\n ", "\n")
          
            for i in configuration_block:
                i = i.rstrip("\n")
                
                res = re.search(i, result, re.DOTALL)
                if res: print("found match")
              
                if res:
                    outfile.write(res.group() + "\n")
                if not res:
                    outfile.write("Config not found for   " + template + " " + ip_address + "\n" + "*" * 20 + "\n")
                    outfile.write(i + "\n")


    tx = threading.Thread(threaded())
    tx.start()
    tx.join()
    print(tx.is_alive())
    print(time.time())
```

Comment: You spawn a single thread that you then await - why would you expect there to be any significant performance difference?

Comment: On a more important point `threading.Thread(threaded())` first calls the `threaded` function on the current thread, then uses its return value for the constructor of the `Thread` object - meaning you're not even moving the call to a different thread (and you probably meant to use `threading.Thread(target=threaded)` instead)

Comment: Hmm, any advice on how I can use multiple threads in this context?

Answer (score 0):

After reading a basic threading tutorial I managed to get it to work. Sorry I've been racking my brain to get this to finish since last night, and have always needed to improve in threading knowledge when iterating through lists.

thanks @UnholySheep for his responses, they helped.

```
def connection_handler(address_list = [], configuration_block=[], dev_type="autodetect"):

listx = []

def threaded(address_variable):

        var = address_variable.split(",")
        ip_address, username, password, secret = str(var[0]).strip(), \
            str(var[1]).strip(), str(var[2]).strip(), str(var[3]).strip()
        connection = ConnectHandler(host=str(ip_address), username=username, password=password,
                                                             secret=secret, device_type=dev_type)
        connection.enable()
        print("*" * 8)
        result = connection.send_command("show run")
        result = result.replace("\n ", "\n")
        #print(repr(result))
        for i in configuration_block:
            i = i.rstrip("\n")
            #print(repr(i))
            print(ip_address)
            res = re.search(i, result, re.DOTALL)
            if res: print("found match")
            #if res: print(res.group() + "\n")
            if res:
                outfile.write(res.group() + "\n")
            if not res:
                outfile.write("Config not found for   " + template + " " + ip_address + "\n" + "*" * 20 + "\n")
                outfile.write(i + "\n")

for i in address_list:
    print(i)
    print("********")

    tx = threading.Thread(target=threaded, args=(i,))
    tx.start()
    print(tx.is_alive())
    listx.append(tx)
for i in listx:
    i.join()
```